# should server side support pagination to use Jetpack component Pagination3 in android?

Tags: android, pagination, client-server

I have noticed that either or both server and client side could support pagination. I have implemented pagination with two different endpoints that support pagination feature from server side. Then, I came up with a curiosity if server side should also support pagination for android(client) to implement pagination feature with Android component Pagination3 while developing android app.
**My question is if server side should support pagination for android to use Pagination3 library? or it is okay for server side **NOT** to support pagination for android to use Pagination3 library?**